# How to update phone number of a auth account by facebook provider

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I have already authenticated with facebook provider in firebase. After authentication, I get back a user object with user details like `name`, `email`, and `phoneNumber`. The requirement is that I need to update `phoneNumber` as phone number I get back in user object is `null`. The phone number is crucial to the app I am building. There is this one option where I first authenticate the user with facebook provider and go to next screen and ask the user for a phone number and authenticate again with a phone number which basically creates a new user with phone number auth provider of the firebase after all this link account created by using facebook auth provider and phone number auth provider, but this method is kind of weird and kind of lot of work to be done just to store user's phone number, is there any other kind of method out there that I am missing? I really need to store user phone number and verify it but need to use facebook provider as the main authentication method.

I am using React Native (Expo) to build the mobile app.

The thing that I have already done, which has not worked for me.

```
let user = auth.currentUser;
user
  .updateProfile({phoneNumber: <PhoneNumberInputFromUser>})
  .then(() => {
    this.navigateToMapView();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // TODO: Handle errors
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Using this does not throw error nor updates `phoneNumber`. But another weird thing here is that it goes to the `then` section of the code and navigates to map view.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are setting the Facebook phone number as the firebase user phone number. To securely do this:

On your server, use the facebook user's access token to query the facebook api for that user's phone number.

Assuming you know the corresponding Firebase user's uid:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(facebookUserFirebaseUid, {phoneNumber: facebookPhoneNumber})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // Return response to client to reload the user to pick up the changes.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred.
  });
```

Comment: did you mean this thing should be done on the server ?? not on the app itself ??

Comment: Yes, this is done on the server. This is a sensitive operation. It can't be an open operation from the client. Otherwise, any user can just update the phone number without any verification. By running it from the server, it is assumed you have some other means to verify the phone number, maybe calling the Facebook API with the access token to verify the user's facebook phone number before you call `updateUser`.